# Python Tools for Visual Studio set breakpoint in child process

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, multiprocessing, ptvs

Is there a way I can set a breakpoint in a child process that Visual Studio can be attached to? I haven't had success with anything I've tried. Example code below.

```
child = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)

def foo():
    print "This is the child process."
    # Breakpoint goes here.
    print "The breakpoint was just hit."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no support for that right now.  You could do Debug->Attach to process and attach to the spawned process but we don't currently have support for attaching automatically.

It's something we might add eventually for improved Django debugging, but I'd suggest opening a feature request on [pytools.codeplex.com](http://pytools.codeplex.com).